# Is there a way to solve for $x$ and $y$ in this simultaneous equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Is there a way to solve for x and y in this simultaneous equation?

$$2x - 3y = 4 $$

$$4x - 6y = 5 $$

Attempt:

I tried solving it but $x$ and $y$ keeps eliminating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, re-write the given equations as follows $$2x-3y=4\implies y=\frac{2}{3}x-\frac{4}{3}\tag 1$$  & $$4x-6y=5\implies y=\frac{2}{3}x-\frac{5}{6}\tag 2$$
both (1) & (2) represent the straight lines which are parallel to each other having slope $\frac{2}{3}$ i.e. the pair of lines are not intersecting hence the given system of linear equations does not have any solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are no solutions to this system since you will always get $5 = 8$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Double the first equation. What does this tell you?

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution. The two equations represent parallel lines which will never intersect.

Rewriting each in terms of $y$ should make this clear:

$$y=\frac{2x}{3}-\frac{4}{3}$$

$$y=\frac{2x}{3}-\frac{5}{6}$$

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Please can you upload the graph to this equation or a link to the graph?

Comment: Equations supplied.

Comment: @user274246 That's what [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2x-3y%3D4%2C+4x-6y%3D5+from+x%3D-10+to+x%3D10+and+from+y%3D-10+to+y%3D10) is for.

Answer (score 1):

Your simultaneous equations have no solutions in $x$ and $y$.

In general, for simultaneous equations, $$a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0$$ and $$a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$$ there will exist unique solutions iff $$\frac{a_1}{a_2} \not =\frac{b_1}{b_2}$$ But it is not so in your case. 
There will be no solutions iff $$\frac{a_1}{a_2} = \frac{b_1}{b_2} \not = \frac{c_1}{c_2}$$ and infinite solutions iff $$\frac{a_1}{a_2} = \frac{b_1}{b_2} = \frac{c_1}{c_2}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are no solutions as these lines are parallel, as one equation is a multiple of the other. Hence, simultaneous equations won't work.

Answer (score 1):

there is no solution because given set of lines are parallel to each other . For confirmation multiply equation number 1 by 2 .

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{cases}
2x - 3y = 4 \\
4x - 6y = 5 \\
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x = 2- \frac{3y}{2}  \\
4x - 6y = 5 \\
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x = 2- \frac{3y}{2}  \\
4\left(2- \frac{3y}{2}\right) - 6y = 5 \\
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x = 2- \frac{3y}{2}  \\
8 = 5 \\
\end{cases}
$$

And $8\neq 5$ so no solutions!